# Getting Contact Phone Number

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I am having trouble getting a contact phone number, i keep getting an error in the log cat saying

```
02-24 19:40:42.772: ERROR/CursorWindow(21467): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 24
```

here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Contacts extends Activity {

private ListView mContactList;
private Button mAddContact;
private boolean mShowInvisible = false;
boolean set;
public String name = "";
public String id;
public String phone;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_listview);

    mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
    mAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);

    mAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i,1);
        }

    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){        
        getContactData(data);
        }
    }

    public void getContactData(Intent data){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Log.v("Contact", contactData.toString());
    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData,null,null,null,null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
            id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Log.v("Contact", "ID: " + id.toString());
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.v("Contact", "Name: " + name.toString());

        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

          while(pCur.moveToNext()){
              phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
              Log.v("getting phone number", "Phone Number: " + phone);
          }
      }

    }

}
```

everything reads fine up until the point where i try to get the phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it, i took out the while loop and i get the number fine now

Comment: I used the same as your code but i got error like Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 23

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be:

```
while(pCur.moveToNext()){
   phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
   Log.v("getting phone number", "Phone Number: " + phone);
}
```

That is, pCur instead of the 'c' cursor, which holds the contacts?

Comment: i am not sure because it never executes the while for some reason even after putting in pCur.moveToFirst() before the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the cursor before calling "moveToNext()". Just call "pCur.moveToFirst();" right before the while. That should help.