# Problems accessing Contacts data

Tags: android

in my app I need to point the user to the contact list, and then receive a selection.
I found [a very descriptive tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/), but I keep getting an uncaught exception.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet(); //NullPointerException on this line

    Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterate.next();
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
    }
    Uri result = data.getData();
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a result: "
        + result.toString());
                break;
            }

        } 
    }
```

EDIT:
Here is the Runtime Exception that is caused by the NullPointerException shown before.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
> ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent {
> dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0n293F45435B45/1 }}
> to activity {com.ptylabs.loveyousms/com.myapps.myApp.MyActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException

And yes, I have the permissions set.

Any ideas whats going on?
Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find what was wrong. So I changed my code to something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112392/getting-contact-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

It's always better if you show us the exception. What I usually do is, on the OnClickListener of the button assigned to go to the Pick Contact Activity I do the following:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

Also, do not forget this in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Your code is working fine here with these two things.

> 08-24 03:24:48.115: VERBOSE/debug(12600): android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME[xxxx@hotmail.com]
>   08-24 03:24:48.115: VERBOSE/debug(12600): Got a result: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/45id8ae8460ccfefc0/37